# Why does my 1Password extension disappear from Safari every time I run MacKeeper?

Tags: safari, 1password

It seems like every time MacKeeper runs, I have trouble with my 1Password extension in Safari. I'm not able to fill my Logins like I normally would.

Comment: It's debatable whether MacKeeper is even a legitimate app, or actually PUP/malware - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacKeeper - **avoid**

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend using an app like MacKeeper. It can strip away necessary files and greatly affect apps that it may not be trying to.

If you choose to continue using it, you should ensure it doesn't cleanup languages (see screenshot below). That modifies the 1Password 7 app bundle, which leads to 1Password no longer passing code signature validation, and ultimately resulting in the Safari App Extension no longer working.

[image: Screenshot of MacKeeper]

Comment: +1 just for the opening sentence ;)